JavaTest Harness with JIRA
Hi I would like to ask if anyone of you know or successfully integrated JIRA to JavaTest Harness?
I want JIRA to be my Defect Tracking Tool for my execution result from JavaTest Harness
Already asked chatGPT and got some answers, but I want to know if anyone of you here already tried integrating the two applications
